Probability of being dealt a perfect hand
This question comes from Frederick Mosteller's Fifty Challenging Problems in Probability.

We often read of someone who has been dealt 13 spades at bridge. With a well-shuffled pack of cards what is the chance that you are dealt a perfect hand (13 of one suit)?

My attempt is as follows:
First we calculate the number of ways you could draw all 13 cards of a suit. This number is given by
$$\text{valid cases} = 4 \times 13!,$$
where the factor of 4 comes from the fact that there are $4$ suits and the factor of $13!$ is just the number of permutations per suit.
Next, we will compute the total number of ways $13$ cards can be dealt. I see two ways of doing this. First, we recognize that for the 1st card we have 52 choices, for the 2nd card we have 51 choices, ... , for the 13th card we have 40 choices. Thus
$$\text{total cases} = 52 \times 51 \times ...\times 40.$$
However, I also see another way of getting the total number of arrangement for 13 cards. Specifically,
$$\text{total cases} = {52 \choose 13} = \frac{52!}{13!39!} = \frac{1}{13!} \left(52\times51\times...\times40 \right)$$
Why do those two methods of counting produce different results?

In one of them, you are counting the unordered hands, and in the other you are counting the ordered hands.  Either way is fine, but you have to be consistent.

I'd have said, unordered is simpler.  There are only $4$ unordered hands that meet the requirement, and $\binom {52}{13}$ unordered hands in general, so the probability is just $4\big /\binom {52}{13}$.

Notice also that your $\text{valid cases}/\text{total cases} = 4/\binom{52}{13}$ which is the same answer as you would get by counting the unordered hands.

As a purely computational note:  always try to avoid large common terms in numerator, denominator.  It is true, of course, that $\frac ab=\frac {a\times N}{b\times N}$ (at least if $N\neq 0$)  but if $N$ is gigantic, you are inviting numerical error by introducing the factor.  $13!$ may not qualify as gigantic, but still.

@lulu Yes I see now! The ${52 \choose 13}$ gives me all the ways I can have 13 cards, but then I need to assign the order of those cards. There are $13!$ ways to do that. Thus $$\text{total cases} = {52 \choose 13} \times 13! = 52 \times 51 \times ... \times 40.$$
Giving agreement between the two cases.

if we are counting only unordered cards of any suit, we can take any card at first = 52 cases, then we can take the remaining 12 cards of that suit in any order therefore 12!. so we get
52*12! / 13 P 52
= 52 * 12! * 40! / 52!
= 40! * 12! / 51!

Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.
